# Population stratification: adjustment via principal components analysis

Tags: pca, genetics, case-control-study

I'm new to statistical genetics and trying to learn more about using principal components to adjust for population stratification in case-control studies.

My understanding is that the PCA approach tries to explain variation in genotypes, some of which could be due to population stratification in a sample with population structure.

The question is this: isn't some of that variation in genotypes also related to true associations between SNPs and case-control status? In particular, in a sample with no population structure, wouldn't the principal components reflect the very signal you are trying to capture?

EDIT: I might have figured this out - it seems that generally "random" SNPs (those not associated with the outcome) are used to infer population structure. If this is true, it would avoid the problem I described above. If I am wrong on this, please do let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are partially correct in that. In general, when we do a disease specific study, we remove the known signals before we calculate the PCs. If it is not a disease study, or if no signals are known, even then, it is fine to use all of the SNPs. The main point is that PC takes the variation across the entire genome whereas disease signals would vary among cases and control only at specific regions. Unless it is a disease with a very high heritability, it shouldn't be big issue. Usually variations across populations along the whole genome are more drastic/detectable than variation across cases and controls along the whole genome. Hence, PCs capture population stratification more than association signals.